# dynamic DNS for 3G USB modem

Tags: networking, dns, 3g

I had a doubt. Is it possible to setup ddns on a 3G dongle ?

I want to be able to connect to the device connected to the dongle from anywhere in the world . That is, even if Ip address changes dynamically, I want to be able to access the device remotely from anywhere in the world by using the hostname and port number ??

Is that possible ?? Can anyone help me on how to do this ??

The device to which the dongle is connected to is the raspberry pi.

Comment: Can't tell you specifics for Raspbian, but I would use either [Tor Domain](https://www.torproject.org/) or [IPv6 tunneling](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6). But it depends on your provider, if there's ipv4/ipv6 and/or NAT involved. Another way would be use of some VPN provider.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and pretty easy, using one of the popular dynamic dns providers, like noip.com or dyndns.com.

You install dynamic dns client software on the computer, which is available for all major operating systems including linux. This software hits your ddns provider's update page on a regular basis, and if your ip has changed, the provider detects that you are coming from a new IP, and updates the DNS for your domain name.

Answer (score -2):

@Michael Krebs is correct. A router has dynamic DNS setting.But 3G dongle doesn't have dynamic DNS setting (when I checked most of the 3G dongles available in India).

I can give you an idea to achieve your requirement.  You can use `TP-Link TL-MR3020` it is  3g dongle to Wi-Fi router. This device has dynamic DNS setting.

Connect the devices in this fashion

`3G-dongle`<kbd>---></kbd> `TP-Link TL-MR3020`<kbd>---></kbd>`Wi-Fi dongle`<kbd>---></kbd> Raspberrypi.

Comment: When you post an answer, take some time to ensure that the formatting of the answer is good. Even if you your solution is right, your answer would get down-voted and eventually be deleted for low quality. Read [How to Answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)